# How to extract strings from a list of string with a condition in flutter?

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart, google-mlkit

I have a list of strings based on google ML kit blocks and i want to get a specific strings in a range between
CHECK # 259395 and SUB-TOTAL..

```
List<String> item = [
      'Line',
       'Restaurant & Cafe',
       'Abdomen',
       '079900000000',
       'VAT# 16669304',
       'TABLE',
       '19-06 2022 12:37',
       'CHECK # 289395 TABLE#',
       '2 MINERAL WATER',
       '1 HOT CHOCOLATE',
       '1 TURKISH COFFEE DOUBLE',
       'SUB-TOTAL',

    ];
```

I just want to display any item between 'CHECK # 259395' and 'SUB-TOTAL' after i extracted these strings from ML kit blocks, the main idea that i want to get only items without any additional information from the invoice.

The items are 2 MINERAL WATER, 1 HOT CHOCOLATE
and 1 TURKISH COFFEE DOUBLE.

Knowing that this data is not static, so it can be changed if i scanned another invoice.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:

```
var result = item.sublist(item.indexOf('CHECK # 259395') + 1, item.indexOf('SUB-TOOTAL'));
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..25: -1

Comment: @FarisShomali that means 'SUB-TOOTAL' isn't in it

Comment: Yes, because when i removed the right side (end) from sublist method the error gone but it didn't show the correct results

Comment: i've updated my question for more information, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
   print(item[index]);
```

in index place which one u want like item[2] will print this '1 HOT CHOCOLATE',

Answer (score -1):

you can easily get like this

item[0]= 'CHECK # 259395',

item[item.length]= 'SUB-TOOTAL',